# How to find the alpha parameter?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let X be a random variable with the following cumulative distribution function:

[image]

I try to sum all after compute the derivative, but I can't reach the correct answer, which is: 0.5.
Any help will be apreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: What are the properties shared by every CDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  What is $\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^+}F(x)$?  What is $\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^-}F(x)$?  (*the limits approaching $\frac{1}{2}$ from the right and the left respectively*)

What does this imply happens with $f(x)$ at $x=\frac{1}{2}$?  What does this imply about $F(x)$ at $x=\frac{1}{2}$?

> $\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^+}F(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ while $\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^-}F(x)=\frac{1}{4}$.  This implies that at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ there is a sudden spike.  Since it has to occur somewhere, and cannot occur *before* $\frac{1}{2}$ and cannot occur *after* $\frac{1}{2}$ it must occur *at* $\frac{1}{2}$.  Thus $f(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{4}$ and $F(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$.